# In Travis-ci, how to commit to the same git repo's branch?

Tags: git, github, travis-ci

I'm doing something very simple, I want Travis to commit to the same branch as the one it is testing.

Part of my .travis.yml file

```
before_install:
- git config --global user.email "travis@travis-ci.org"
- git config --global user.name "Travis CI"
- git config --global push.default simple
- git remote set-url origin https://${GH_TOKEN}@github.com/MY/REPO.git
script:
- [DO STUFF]
- git add ./bin/*
- git commit --message "Travis build $TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER"
- git push origin HEAD
```

My issue lies with `git push origin HEAD`. What should it be if I want it to commit to the same branch? I've tried: `git push origin HEAD` and `git push origin $TRAVIS_BRANCH`

Answer (score 0):

```
branch_name=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`
git push origin $branch_name
```

But that wouldn't work if Travis has checked out commit not at the head of a branch.

Comment: Get the name of a branch  from HEAD and push the branch to origin. If HEAD is not at the head of a branch — ouch.